# How do array updates with = work in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

I understand that I can write

```
myArray(index) = newValue
```

to update an array. However, I don't understand how this works internally. I learned from another question here that `=` is usually not a method call in Scala. I also understand that the brackets are shorthand for calling the `apply()` method on an object, so I assume `myArray(index)` means `myArray.apply(index)`.

But how does it work to assign a value to something that has just been returned from a method call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that

```
myArray(index)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
myArray.apply(index)
```

However, adding an assignment with the `=` operator completely changes the meaning:

```
myArray(index) = newValue
```

is a special syntax for the `update` method:

```
myArray.update(index, newValue)
```

---

This does not only apply for Arrays; you can make use of it on your own. In fact, many classes in the Scala Collections Framework make use of this syntactic sugar. For example, the [`scala.collection.mutable.Map#update(A,B)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map@update(key:A,value:B):Unit) can also do this.

```
class MyClass(var i: Int)
{
    def update(i: Int, j: Int) = { this.i = i + j }
}

var my = new MyClass(1)
my(1) = 2
println(my.i) // prints 3
```

Comment: Does this work for all classes? Does it mean there is a general rule, or is it only working for arrays? If it is special, how can I specify something similar for my own classes?

Comment: Edited my answer to address you comment.

Comment: @lex82: As a general rule, Scala works very hard to have only general rules ;-) Contrary to popular belief, Scala is a pretty simple language, simpler than Java, for example, precisely because it tries to have only a few powerful general rules and no special cases, corner cases, boundary cases, special built-in magic syntax, etc.

Comment: Heres the relevant section of the SLS. It explains quite nicely how the expressions are expanded: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignments